# I want to ... travel to France ? take a trip to France ? spend a week in France?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

What expression do you use to express your hope and desire to go to a foreign country and spend some time there for pleasure ?

What comes to my mind and sounds natural is not one expression.

> Yeah, I want to go to France.
>   Maybe spend a few weeks.
>   Just walk around and eat the local food.

Many EFL textbooks here ( South Korea) and students (native Korean speakers) use this expression often.

> I want to travel to France.

What expression would you use in combination with **I want to** ?

Can these be used to mean that you want to go to a foreign country and spend some time for pleasure ?

> 1. I want to take a trip to France.
> 2. I want to go on a trip to France.
> 3. I want to travel to France.

From what I could understand from the definitions on Wiktionary and Oxford Online English dictionary, **travel** has more to do with the action of an object moving through an area. While **trip** has more to do with going to some place for pleasure.

What would be the most natural way of expressing the idea of going to a foreign country and spending some time there for pleasure ?

Comment: The phrase that comes to mind for me would be: "I would love to take a trip to France."  This conveys a more emtional than using 'want'.  I'd be curious of other answers though as this just may be my own dialect talking.

Comment: The word vacation came to mind last night and fits very well.  "I want to take a vacation in France."  You can use it as a verb as well, but it feels slightly weird because of the tion ending - "I want to vacation in France."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't imagine why anyone would want to go to France, but anyway ... :-)

All three of your sentences are valid and common. I'd also add a fourth: "I want to visit France."

All mean pretty much the same thing. I don't think most fluent English speakers would make a distinction between "travel" and "trip" in such a context. Well, "travel" is a verb and "trip" is a noun, so they're used different. But "I want to travel to ..." and "I want to take a trip to ..." are pretty much synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much detail and specific information you want to convey. People use a variety of words that may not be necessary when speaking. When people speak about a desire to travel, they don't need to use the words "travel" or "trip" because those may be implied by what else they say. As a native speaker, I would say any of the following:

*I want to go to France.* [This is the most simple phrasing. US English speakers use "go to" in many, many sentences.]

*I want to take a trip to France, but not a guided tour.*
[the reason for including "take a trip" is because I'm also speaking about the *kind* of trip -- not just the desire to be in France.]

*I want to travel to Paris by train from London.* [Again, I use the word "travel" because I'm talking about the method of getting there, not just the desire to be in Paris.]

*I have always wanted to see France, so I'm saving money to take a trip there.*